# Investigate about vanished shelveset

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, shelveset

As stated in the title, in the last few day i lost a shelveset.
I successfully archived it friday, and then was unable to find it the next monday. It litterally vanished.

Now i'm tring to find a way to retrieve it, or if it's not possible, at least to dig into TFS log to figure out what happened.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.
Clearly this is a community specific question, for that reason i choose the tag that identify that community (TFS users).
And there are no debug detail, because i'm asking where to find log file or backup, in a very specific product (so the question is only for a community).
If specific question about TFS is too community specific, please remove that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a shelveset

1. In Team Explorer, choose  Home, and then choose Pending Changes.
2. Choose the **Actions** link, and then choose **Find Shelvesets**.
3. On the Find Shelvesets page, enter the name or alias of a project
   team member in the box, and then choose the Enter key.

[image]

Besides, you could also check it in database. Shelvesets are stored as workspaces in tbl_Workspace with the type = 1.

The following SQL will show you all of your shelvesets:

```
use TfsVersionControl;

select  * from tbl_workspace where type = 1
```

If you are still not able to find that shelveset from database, afraid you didn't archived successfully or there was something wrong when you archived it.